Using JQ to parse timestamp
I am having some difficulty finding my error with JQ parsing this timestamp.
"time": "2024-05-13 16:43:06.928708"

.time| strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")| strftime("%Y")
It clearly is not agreeing that I have this format, however this is exactly the format I'm using in Python.
here is the error message received.
"2024-05-13 16:43:06.928708" does not match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
What gives, do I need some ticks somewhere?

While the Go implementation of jq actually can parse %f correctly:
gojq '.time | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") | strftime("%Y")'

If all you need is %Y from a date string that is already formatted starting with %Y-, just extract its first four characters:
jq '.time[:4]'

Demo

Well buried in git issues JQ does not support %f so there are a number of solutions to work around this.
As soon as I remove the .%f jq is able to parse the dates.
Fortunately in my case I can change the format to whatever I need it to be.

This does not really answer the question.
